# create-react-app live reloading with proxy

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

We're developing a web app in React using create-react-app. The backend is written in Python and therefore we define a `proxy` in `package.json` to forward API calls to it during development as described [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development).

This, however, seems to interfere with the live reloading of the React development server when a source file is modified. In the Browser console we see:

> The development server has disconnected.
>   Refresh the page if necessary.

And the backend server sees unexpected requests:

> 127.0.0.1 - - [22/May/2019 08:01:38] "GET /sockjs-node/227/inixucqn/websocket HTTP/1.1" 401 -

Is there any way to fix this? I guess we could [configure the proxy manually](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development#configuring-the-proxy-manually), but this must be a problem everyone has when using `proxy`.